# android ble setValue is 0x00010000

Tags: java, android, binary, integer, string-formatting

I have one function :

```
public static String toPaddedHex(int i) {
    return String.format("0x%04X", i);
}

//print

System.out.println(toPaddedHex(1));  // 0x0001
```

if I want print is "0x00010000" 
what do I do ?

Comment: this code works as expected http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMUFdqaGQ0TGtXa1U

Comment: it yields `0x0001`

Comment: YES, but I want "0x00010000" , not only "0x0001"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
public static String toPaddedHex(int i,int shift) {
    return String.format("0x%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(i<<shift)).replace(' ', '0')
}
```

[Demo](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMRkhoS1lnWTJ2VFE)

Comment: Check answer. Shift 4 left.

Comment: I don't understand Shift 4 left ?

Comment: Edit try again.